# How can I prioritize a ssh Forwarded Agent over an Identity File?

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-agent

I was previously able to connect to my a server with ssh agent forwarding:

```
ssh -A my.server
```

And from there connect to another host on the server's network that had my public key in the `authorized_keys` file:

```
server:~# ssh another.host
```

This worked fine until I created a public/private key pair on the server, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Now when I try and connect I get: `Permission denied (publickey).`

I believe what's happening is that the server's key `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is being attempted and failing before the forwarded agent's key is being attempted.

There's probably way to turn up the number of allowed attempts on `my.server`, but I was hoping there would be another configuration option to prioritize trying the key that is forwarded from the agent - similar to how `IdentitiesOnly` `IdentityFile` can be used to control which keys are tried for a particular server - or an option to disable the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key from being attempted for a particular host - without having to rename it and specify it for all other hosts ( allowing it to remain a real default )

Also, I don't want to add the public key from `my.server` to `another.host` - I only want that connection to happen when I'm logged into `my.server` with agent forwarding.

Answer (score 3):

It is a little bit more complicated than that. The client offers all keys that are available and after several of them fails, it fails completely.

You can see that from the verbose log if you add `-vvv` to the command line. Using `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` can help.

Also it can help to reduce the amount of the keys you have in your local `ssh-agent`.

The last thing I can think of is to move that `id_rsa` from default location (client is reading the files in default location always and it can't be turned off) and configure in `~/.ssh/config` that it will be used on the hosts where you need it only.

Comment: Thanks! How can I check to see what keys are available via forwarding?

Comment: `ssh-add -l` and `ssh-add -L` will list all the keys in the agent. All of them are used in the listed order.

Comment: After I ssh into `my.server` both of those give me `The agent has no identities.` which I don't think it accurate...

Comment: So in that case, the problem will be somewhere else (the keys are most probably not added to the agent and used directly from `ssh` in the first connection).